# How to determine the length of a very large file

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-handling

I am currently working on a filter prototype that works with GNSS data.

The files that I`m supposed to work with are large (with sizes close to 60GB).
Because of this, I am trying to run parallel processes on different portions of the file in order to reduce the run-time.
I'm opening the file with np.fromfile which allows me to read a specified number of elements, with the possibility of adding an offset when it comes to where I want the reading operation to start from.

My question is: how can I determine the number of elements inside the file without parsing the entire file first, as this would add a lot to the execution time of the code.

An idea that I had was to return this value from the append method that python uses, since it automatically determines where the last element of the file is.

Comment: The run time is related to your disk I/O performances. Adding more processes will not speed things up on standard disks. Is your code running on a cluster with specific filesystem that supports parallel access?

Comment: @Demi-Lune I want to implement multiprocessing in order to speed up the part which analyses the files. The problem that I would like to address with knowing the size of the file is the automation of data handling of each process (allocate a chunk of the file to a specific process for analysis).

Comment: The answer to your question strongly depends on the file format. You should add a relevant description, reference or example.

Comment: And your idea with "python's append method" is not clear. Are you talking about [file.seek(offset, whence)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) ?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "parallel processes" ? If it means multithreading with shared memory (as opposed to MPI with distributed memory),  why don't you sequentially read the file, then dispatch the data?

Comment: (by the way, this is why stackoverflow recommends adding an example and [show some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It helps to focus the question)